# How to add a checklistbox to an Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, components

I'm working as a support engineer on a complex solution, based on several distinct applications, and regularly I get questions on a certain feature, covered by (multiple) applications, mentioning certain events (memory leaks, going into crashes, ...).

I'm currently building an Excel sheet, where I have one column, called "Processes/Features", which should contain a checklistbox, mentioning the applications and the features and the events, so that I can check several ones of them.

Unfortunately:

- When I choose "Developer" menu, "Insert", "Combo List - Edit", this seems to be disabled, and I'm not even sure if this is what I'm looking for.
- When I choose "Developer" menu, "Add-ins", I don't find what I'm looking for.

Does anybody know how to add a `CheckListBox` to my Excel sheet?

**Edit**

It seems to be possible to download ActiveX controls and add them to my Excel sheet. If I do that, what will other users see who open the Excel sheet when they don't have added the ActiveX on their PC?

Comment: Add Check Box to the Sheet is not big task,, but the crucial one is what you are trying to achieve!! Better make the issue more clear and add some screen shot also to show the expected result.

Comment: Meanwhile to this ,,, Click `Developer Tab` then hit `Design` and finally left to it you find `Insert`. From the pop up list find `Active X Control` select 3rd one `Active X Checkbox Control` ☺

Comment: @RajeshS: The checkbox control only contains one item, I'm looking for a checklistbox, which contains multiple items which can be checked.

Comment: ,,, for multiple Checkbox first select & draw GROUP CONTROL you find in Form Control category on same pop up menu then draw as many Checkbox controls inside Group Control. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS: thanks for your reply, but it's quite disappointing: when I was programming in Delphi, the VCL (Visual Component Library) contained a TCheckListBox (a listbox of checkable items), and as I have stopped working with Delphi in 2002, I figured that such a component would be available anywhere (and in case not anywhere there would now be an add-in for that), hence my question.

Comment: my solution is based on Excel not for Delphi,, and what I've suggested is 100% working for EXcel.  If you need solution for Delphi the modify the post !!

Comment: @RajeshS: indeed, that's what I said: my question is for Excel and your comment has answered my question. I was merely saying to be surprised to see that a component, so generally known in Delphi, is not even present in Excel, after all those years. Can you put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?